# Backbone js collection of collections issue

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I'm running into an isssue when I try to create a collection of collections using backbone js.
Here is the code :

Models and Collections :

```
var Track = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {
      title : ""
    }
})

var TrackCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : Track,
})

var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {
        name : "",
        tracks : new TrackCollection,
    }
})

var PlaylistCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : Playlist,
})
```

Creation of the playlist collection :

```
var playlists = new PlaylistCollection;

// create and push the first playlist
playlists.push({ name : "classic" });
// create and push a track in the playlist just created
playlists.last().get("tracks").push({ title : "fur elise" });

// create and push the second playlist
playlists.push({ name : "c2c" });
// create and push a track in the playlist just created
playlists.last().get("tracks").push({ title : "fuya" });

// display first playlist
console.log(JSON.stringify(playlists.at(0).toJSON()))
// display second playlist
console.log(JSON.stringify(playlists.at(1).toJSON()))
```

Here is the output :

```
{"name":"classic","tracks":[{"title":"fur elise"},{"title":"fuya"}]}
{"name":"c2c","tracks":[{"title":"fur elise"},{"title":"fuya"}]}
```

The problem is, as we can see on the output, the 2 playlists have the 2 tracks "fur elise" and "fuya".

So my question is why ? and what should I do in order to have "fur elise" only in the first playlist named "classic" and "fuya" only in the second playlist named "c2c" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is your default `tracks` attribute in `PlayList`:

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : "",
        tracks : new TrackCollection,
    }
});
```

Backbone will shallow-copy the [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) when creating new instances:

> **defaults** `model.defaults or model.defaults()`
>   [...]
>   *Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances.*

The result is that every single `PlayList` instance that uses the default `tracks` will be using exactly the same `TrackCollection` as its `tracks` attribute and that `TrackCollection` will be the one referenced in the `defaults`.

The easiest solution is to use a function for `defaults`:

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : function() {
        return {
            name : "",
            tracks : new TrackCollection,
        };
    }
});
```

That way the `defaults` function will be called when defaults are needed and each time `defaults` is called you'll get a brand new `TrackCollection` in the default `tracks` attribute.

Here's a quick rule of thumb for you:

> If you want to put anything other than strings, numbers, or booleans in `defaults`, use a `defaults` function instead of a `defaults` object.

Comment: You're totally right, I thought it was doing a copy of the defaults at the instantiation. Anyways, thanks a lot for your response !

Comment: this is great info and very pertinent but might it simply be easier and more clear to create a new collection in the initialization method?

Comment: @AlexMills: Maybe. I didn't know enough about their situation to say. This answer is more of a "if you're going to do this, then do it this way" sort of thing.

Comment: thanks Mu, one question for you - I'd like to call into question the thing you said about defaults as an object versus defaults as a function. In one of my models, my default is an object and all my default properties are null values, but that doesn't mean when I create an new instance of that model all the other previously created instances values all become null. How can this coincide with what you said about sharing a single value?

Comment: @AlexMills: `null` is non-mutable, an array or object is not: https://jsfiddle.net/7z0c7f6e/