# nested json in backboneJS view

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have this json as follow

```
[
 {
    "name":"River In 1", 
    "lat": 3.277801, 
    "lng": 101.681199,
    y: 55.11,
    drilldown: {
        data: [{"x":1.3722048e+12,"y":72.21},
                     {"x":1.3722057e+12,"y":67.84},
                     {"x":1.3722066e+12,"y":71.47},
                     {"x":1.3722075e+12,"y":71.22},
                     {"x":1.3722084e+12,"y":69.84},
                     {"x":1.3722093e+12,"y":65.19},
                     {"x":1.3722102e+12,"y":75.35},
                     {"x":1.3722111e+12,"y":75.32},
                     {"x":1.372212e+12,"y":70.31},
                     {"x":1.3722129e+12,"y":68.84},
                     {"x":1.3722138e+12,"y":66.19}]
    }   
},
{
    "name":"River In 2", 
    "lat": 3.272488, 
    "lng": 101.685491,
    y: 21.63,
    drilldown: {
        data: [{"x":1.3722048e+12,"y":72.21},
                     {"x":1.3722057e+12,"y":67.84},
                     {"x":1.3722066e+12,"y":71.47},
                     {"x":1.3722075e+12,"y":71.22},
                     {"x":1.3722084e+12,"y":69.84},
                     {"x":1.3722093e+12,"y":65.19},
                     {"x":1.3722102e+12,"y":75.35},
                     {"x":1.3722111e+12,"y":75.32},
                     {"x":1.372212e+12,"y":70.31},
                     {"x":1.3722129e+12,"y":68.84},
                     {"x":1.3722138e+12,"y":66.19}]
    }
},
{
    "name":"Ext River 1", 
    "lat": 3.288770, 
    "lng": 101.695583,
    y: 11.94,
    drilldown: {
            data: [{"x":1.3722048e+12,"y":72.21},
                         {"x":1.3722057e+12,"y":67.84},
                         {"x":1.3722066e+12,"y":71.47},
                         {"x":1.3722075e+12,"y":71.22},
                         {"x":1.3722084e+12,"y":69.84},
                         {"x":1.3722093e+12,"y":65.19},
                         {"x":1.3722102e+12,"y":75.35},
                         {"x":1.3722111e+12,"y":75.32},
                         {"x":1.372212e+12,"y":70.31},
                         {"x":1.3722129e+12,"y":68.84},
                         {"x":1.3722138e+12,"y":66.19}]
    }
},
{
    "name":"Ext River 2", 
    "lat": 3.284699, 
    "lng": 101.691960,
    y: 7.15,
    drilldown: {
            data: [{"x":1.3722048e+12,"y":72.21},
                         {"x":1.3722057e+12,"y":67.84},
                         {"x":1.3722066e+12,"y":71.47},
                         {"x":1.3722075e+12,"y":71.22},
                         {"x":1.3722084e+12,"y":69.84},
                         {"x":1.3722093e+12,"y":65.19},
                         {"x":1.3722102e+12,"y":75.35},
                         {"x":1.3722111e+12,"y":75.32},
                         {"x":1.372212e+12,"y":70.31},
                         {"x":1.3722129e+12,"y":68.84},
                         {"x":1.3722138e+12,"y":66.19}]
    }       
},
{
    "name":"Ext River 3", 
    "lat": 3.273645, 
    "lng": 101.690136,
    y: 2.14,
    drilldown: {
        data: [{"x":1.3722048e+12,"y":72.21},
                     {"x":1.3722057e+12,"y":67.84},
                     {"x":1.3722066e+12,"y":71.47},
                     {"x":1.3722075e+12,"y":71.22},
                     {"x":1.3722084e+12,"y":69.84},
                     {"x":1.3722093e+12,"y":65.19},
                     {"x":1.3722102e+12,"y":75.35},
                     {"x":1.3722111e+12,"y":75.32},
                     {"x":1.372212e+12,"y":70.31},
                     {"x":1.3722129e+12,"y":68.84},
                     {"x":1.3722138e+12,"y":66.19}]
    }
}
]
```

and i refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890439/mapping-json-to-backbone-js-collections) and no solution satisfied my level of knowledge about backboneJS.

Normally i used to get it like model.get('name') but couldn't get the nested item/object. Anyone can help to get item in the 'drilldown'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `drilldown` is directly set as a model attribute, you would first use `model.get('drilldown')`. Then we get to `data` as a property with `model.get('drilldown').data` and then iterate over the `data` property which is an array:

```
for (var i = 0, data = model.get('drilldown').data; i < data.length; i++) {
   // Each array element data[i] has a x and y property
   console.log(data[i].x, data[i].y);  // Logs 1.3722057e+12, 67.84
}
```

Comment: your solution seems easy for to understand but i think i have error on the json return. I'm not sure which json part is missing.

Comment: error trigger during fetch, so i tried to catch the error but nothing hint me to the cause

Comment: Yep, if you pass the data into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com), it doesn't validate because all properties and values need to be in quotes: such as  `"y": 11.94,"drilldown": ` So just make all the `y`, `drilldown`, and `data` properties quoted.