# Backbone "remembering" values in properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a basic model:

```
myTestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: 'My Title',
        config: {},
        active: 1,
    }
})
```

Nothing special there, however I've noticed values in the `config` option are remembered between instances. For example:

```
var test1 = new myTestModel();
test1.set('title', 'A New Title');
test1.get('config').screen_name = 'Joe';
alert( test1.get('title') );               // 'A New Title', expected.
alert( test1.get('config').screen_name );  // 'Joe', expected.

var test2 = new myTestModel();
alert( test2.get('title') );               // 'My Title', expected.
alert( test2.get('config').screen_name );  // 'Joe', NOT expected.
```

So, why in `test2`, is the `screen_name` being preserved from `test1`? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone js collection of collections issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675539/backbone-js-collection-of-collections-issue) (same underlying problem and solution at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stumbled upon one of the gotchas in Javascript, as noted in the doc for [`model.defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults):

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if
>   you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all
>   instances. Instead, define defaults as a function.

You can use a function instead of a hash to set your defaults:

```
myTestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            title: 'My Title',
            config: {},
            active: 1
        };
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Y7PYj/

Comment: Ugh, of course. That makes sense now, looking at it. Thank you.